# Installing pyspark on hadoop and yarn

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have installed spark on top of `hadoop` and `yarn`.
when I launch the `pyspark shell` and try to compute something I get this error.

```
Error from python worker:
  /usr/bin/python: No module named pyspark
```

The `pyspark` module should be there, do I have to put an external link to it?

Comment: please update with your system config. OS, Hadoop and Yarn version etc.

Comment: There is not enough information in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same problem. It was due to building Spark with Java7. Using Java6 should fix it. It's actually python's fault - its zipimport module does not support the Zip64 format used by Java7 to package large Jar with 65536+ files.
This was the Google hit that helped me.
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-spark-user/201406.mbox/%3CCAMJOb8kcGk0PqiOGJu6UoKCeysWCuSW3xwd5wRs8ikpMgD2DAg@mail.gmail.com%3E

This also explains it.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1911